# how to write an offer like this one?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

> In "kids" offer, you can get the "kids meal" and **another** meal. **For this other meal**, you can choose between "Chicken meal" or "Beef meal".

I feel like using the phrases (Another meal) and (for this other meal) is not suitable. I asked someone I know what do you call a meal for adults, he said that it's just called a "meal". So how can I make sure that our clients understand that there's only one type of kids meal and two types of "Adults" meal and they can choose one of them?

Are the phrases correct and okay to use? I need the sentence to be as short as possible.

Comment: I think it's a bit weird to offer a free "regular / adult" meal when purchasing a "kid's meal". Since in nearly every case the *adult* would be paying (for a full-sized meal which you would expect to be more expensive than a child's meal), it seems far more natural to offer a free child's meal with every adult meal purchased, rather than the other way around.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think OP said either meal would be free - perhaps it's just a combo?

Comment: @FumbleFingers @A C Yes, it's more like a combo. You get discount on both meals. I'm not the person who put this rules. I'm just a customer service representative and I should do whatever they tell me. Maybe they wanna emphasize that we have a meal for kids and they encourage ppl to buy it by giving them discount on regular meals.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Buy any beef or chicken meal - get a **Free** kid's meal *

Then you put any restrictions in really small type right at the bottom of the page...

<sub>* Kid's meal is chicken nuggets & chips. One kid's meal offer per adult. Child must be accompanied by parent or guardian. Under 14s only. Terms & conditions apply. Participating outlets only.</sub>

## ;-)

More seriously, the way you have it worded at present makes it sound like any child can walk in, buy themselves a kid's meal, then get a free large meal for their parent... which I imagine is not how the offer works.

If it's an advert - a poster or in-store offer - you need to get the essential message across really quickly. Details come later.
Get them to understand that what you are actually selling is the beef meal & the chicken meal.
The "special offer" is the kid's meal.
Don't give them the impression, however fleeting, that what they are about to pay for is the kid's meal. It's not worth the arguments at the till between your staff & the customers who don't read so well, or don't read thoroughly.

Answer (score 9):

In American English, the phrase **a regular meal** is often used in fast-food contexts to refer to an adult meal that is a regular part of the menu.

So you could say

> Buy one kid's meal, and get a regular meal for free<sup>†</sup>

<sup>†</sup><sub>beef or chicken.</sub>

or

> Buy one kid's meal, and get a regular beef or chicken meal for free

Comment: The † might fit better after "regular" or "meal", instead of after "free".

Answer (score 3):

> So how can I make sure that our clients understand that there's only one type of kids meal and two types of "Adults" meal and they can choose one of them?

You have almost answered your own question!

> There is one type of kid's meal and two types of adult meal, *beef* or *chicken*. For the *Kids Offer* you may choose one adult and one kid's meal.

Using phrases like "another meal" is *wordy*, and unclear

Answer (score 0):

List the childrens offer separate from the adult offers.
In the children's section (where you spell out what the "kids meal" is), mention that a kids meal is free with an adult Chicken or Beef meal.
(OR that an an adult Chicken or Beef meal is free with "kids meal" purchase if that is what you really meant to say in your question)

"Kids Meal" is a generally accepted phrase that won't cause offense, but some people don't like for their "children" to be called kids.
Not sure this applies in UK and doesn't apply everywhere in the USA (it is an individual preference, not a regional thing).

"Kids Meal" is generally less expensive than most other 'adult' items.